# How to get beans with custom annotation via ArC in quarkus?

Tags: cdi, quarkus

I want to find beans at runtime depending on user input, so using io.quarkus.arc.Arc.

However, I cannot figure out how to get beans with custom annotation in a reasonable way. Only got something working by implementing the annotation interface like:

```
InstanceHandle<Service> instanceHandleA = Arc.container()
.instance(Service.class, new SupportsJobTypeImpl(JobType.A));

InstanceHandle<Service> instanceHandleB = Arc.container()
.instance(Service.class, new SupportsJobTypeImpl(JobType.B));



class SupportsJobTypeImpl implements SupportsJobType {
        JobType requestedJobType;

        public SupportsJobTypeImpl(JobType requestedJobType) {
            this.requestedJobType = requestedJobType;
        }

        @Override
        public JobType value() {
            return requestedJobType;
        }

        @Override
        public Class<? extends Annotation> annotationType() {
            return SupportsJobType.class;
        }
}
```

Is there a way to get instanceHandleA, instanceHandleB with less cumbersome verbose code like SupportsJobTypeImpl?

Background info about my test code:

```
public enum JobType {
    A,B
}


@Qualifier
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target({METHOD, FIELD, PARAMETER, TYPE})
public @interface SupportsJobType {
    JobType value();
}


@ApplicationScoped
@SupportsJobType(JobType.A)
public class ServiceForA extends Service {
}

@ApplicationScoped
@SupportsJobType(JobType.B)
public class ServiceForB extends Service {
}
```

UPDATE: Tried to get it working by including SupportsJobTypeImpl in the SupportsJobType annotation interface (like in the example from https://docs.jboss.org/cdi/api/2.0/javax/enterprise/util/AnnotationLiteral.html):

```
@Qualifier
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target({METHOD, FIELD, PARAMETER, TYPE})
public @interface SupportsJobType {
    JobType value();

    public abstract class Literal extends AnnotationLiteral<SupportsJobType> implements SupportsJobType {
        JobType requestedJobType;

        public Literal() {
        }


        @Override
        public JobType value() {
            return requestedJobType;
        }

        @Override
        public Class<? extends Annotation> annotationType() {
            return SupportsJobType.class;
        }
    }
}
```

however, I get no bean instance from ArC by:

```
InstanceHandle<Service> instanceHandleA = Arc.container().instance(Service.class, new SupportsJobType.Literal() {
    public JobType value() {
        return JobType.A;
    }
});
```

UPDATE2: also not working:

```
@Qualifier
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target({METHOD, FIELD, PARAMETER, TYPE})
public @interface SupportsJobType {
    JobType value();

    class Literal extends AnnotationLiteral<SupportsJobType> implements SupportsJobType {
        JobType requestedJobType;

        public Literal(JobType requestedJobType) {
            this.requestedJobType = requestedJobType;
        }

        @Override
        public JobType value() {
            return requestedJobType;
        }

        @Override
        public Class<? extends Annotation> annotationType() {
            return SupportsJobType.class;
        }
    }
}
```

I get no bean instance from ArC by:

```
InstanceHandle<Service> instanceHandleA = Arc.container().instance(Service.class, new SupportsJobType.Literal(JobType.A));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell, what you're doing is exactly what you should do. It is idiomatic for implementations of annotation types to be nested in the annotation type itself, be called `Literal` and extend the `AnnotationLiteral` class. For example (writing from memory):

```java
@Qualifier
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target({METHOD, FIELD, PARAMETER, TYPE})
public @interface SupportsJobType {
    JobType value();

    class Literal extends AnnotationLiteral<SupportsJobType> implements SupportsJobType {
        private final JobType value;

        public Literal(JobType value) {
            this.value = value;
        }

        @Override
        public JobType value() {
            return value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. Marking your answer as solution, added small quarkus related config fix as self-answer below

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was stumbling over a small detail like mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/a/66980506/753724
which means I simply had to add `@Unremovable` to beans resulting in:

```
@ApplicationScoped
@Unremovable
@SupportsJobType(JobType.A)
public class ServiceForA extends Service {
}

@ApplicationScoped
@Unremovable
@SupportsJobType(JobType.B)
public class ServiceForB extends Service {
}
```

With the slightly adapted Annotation class (only new static method):

```
@Qualifier
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target({METHOD, FIELD, PARAMETER, TYPE})
public @interface SupportsJobType {
    JobType value();

    class Literal extends AnnotationLiteral<SupportsJobType> implements SupportsJobType {
        JobType requestedJobType;


        public Literal(JobType requestedJobType) {
            this.requestedJobType = requestedJobType;
        }

        public static Literal of(JobType value) {
            return new Literal(value);
        }

        @Override
        public JobType value() {
            return requestedJobType;
        }

        @Override
        public Class<? extends Annotation> annotationType() {
            return SupportsJobType.class;
        }
    }
}
```

the beans were found as expected by:

```
InstanceHandle<Service> instanceHandleA = Arc.container().instance(Service.class, SupportsJobType.Literal.of(JobType.A));

InstanceHandle<Service> instanceHandleB = Arc.container().instance(Service.class, SupportsJobType.Literal.of(JobType.B));
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. Also it might be useful to mention that I get ride of this problem by adding @Named to bean as in https://quarkus.io/guides/cdi-reference#remove_unused_beans asserted that these beans does not remove in optimization process